# How can I write my own decorator using xlwings decorators to create Excel UDFs

Tags: xlwings

I would like to write my own decorator to create UDFs in Excel using xlwings decorator. However, when I import my function, the function name imported is the decorator inner function name's.

A dummy example to clarify:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw

def to_excel(f): # my decorator
    @xw.func
    @xw.arg('xl_app', vba='Application')
    def wrapped(xl_app, arg1 =None, arg2 =None):
        # do some stuff
        return len(f(arg1, arg2))
    return wrapped

def foo(dim1, dim2): 
    dim1, dim2 =int(dim1), int(dim2)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.ones((dim1, dim2)))

@to_excel
def xlFoo(*args, **kwargs): # Excel UDF
    return foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I import it into Excel, it will auto generate the below VBA code:

```
'Autogenerated code by xlwings - changes will be lost with next import! 
Function wrapped(Optional arg1, Optional arg2)  
        If TypeOf Application.Caller Is Range Then On Error GoTo failed 
        wrapped = Py.CallUDF("xl2", "wrapped", Array(Application, arg1, arg2), ThisWorkbook, Application.Caller)    
        Exit Function   
failed: 
        wrapped = Err.Description   
End Function
```

If I replace `wrapped` by `xlFoo`, it now works as expected:

```
Function xlFoo(Optional arg1, Optional arg2)    
        If TypeOf Application.Caller Is Range Then On Error GoTo failed 
        xlFoo = Py.CallUDF("xl2", "xlFoo", Array(Application, arg1, arg2), ThisWorkbook, Application.Caller)    
        Exit Function   
failed: 
        xlFoo = Err.Description 
End Function
```

Comment: What is the end goal of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a set of functions that all returns results in the same format. I wrote a function using xlwings decorator that asynchronously write this format in excel. Turning this function in a decorator seemed an easy way to allow their use from excel.

Comment: Note quite sure if that helps, but have a look at the new dynamic arrays int v0.10: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#dynamic-array-formulas

Comment: @FelixZumstein Love it! Two remarks: 1 - it deletes adjacent cells even though they were not returned by the function. 2 - using Excel rand() function as input triggers an infinite loop.

Comment: True, 1) is currently a "feature" but I agree that it needs improvement, stay tuned for future releases or better even, open an issue on GitHub 2) Makes sense, as rand() is a volatile function but thanks for bringing this up.